# I am trying to find the lower and higher bound of a function or big(o) and big(Omega)

Tags: runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

```
for (i = n; i > 0; i -= 2) {  
    if (i % 2 == 0) {  
        q = i  
        while (q != 0) {  
            q -= 2  
        }  
    }
}
```

I have this function here and I am trying to find the lower and upper bound. I think that big(Omega) should be o(n) and big(o) would be o(n^2). My reasoning is that is the best case would be when n == 1, so only the outer loop would have to run. Furthermore, the worst case would be when both the inner loop and outer loop would have to run. So, looking at the outer-loop it should run in o(n) complexity and the inner while will run o(n) as well because the amount times i runs is equivalent to n. Therefore, big(o) is o(n^2) and big (omega) is o(n). I was wondering is my thinking correct?

I looked through each line of the function and thought about the worst and best case scenario.

Comment: You don't determine these by picking n.

Comment: I see. so then would the worst case and base case not be n^2 and n, respectively. I guess I am just confused on how to find the best and worst case without picking an n value.

Comment: You have no variable input here - best and worst case will be identical.

Comment: Does that mean that worst and best case would be o(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

On line 1, you loop n/2 times.

On line 2, the 'if' condition is true only when **i** is even.

This 'if' tells if we must execute the 'while' inner loop.

If **i** is odd then your `if` condition is never true as i % 2 is always == 1 in that case.

If **i** is even then your `if` condition is always true.

So the best case condition is when **i** is odd, your worst case condition is when **i** is even. Looking at your `for` loop, **i** is always odd if **n** is odd, and **i** is always even if **n** is even.

> **So the best case condition is when **n** is odd, your worst case condition is when **n** is even.**

Best case : as we **never** enter the `if` clause, the complexity of the best case is the complexity of the top `for` loop, which is Omega(n/2) = **Omega(n)**.

Worst case: we **always** enter the `if` clause, so we **always** execute the `while` loop.

The number of loop executed by your `while` is dependent on i which is decreasing by 2 each time we loop through the `for`.

So the number of loops of the `while` is a classic arithmetic progression :

```
n + (n-2) + (n-4) + ... + 4 + 2 = n*(1+n) = n^2 + n
```

This comes from the formula of the first n even numbers :

```
S = 2 + 4 + 6 + ... + (2n-2) + 2n = n * (1 + n)
```

So the complexity of the worst case is **O(n^2)**.